# trying to print below output by query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables Client, Property and Owner below are their schemas,

```
create table Property (property_no varchar(20), p_address varchar(50), rent_start date, rent_finish 
date, rent_per_day int, primary key(property_no,rent_start, rent_finish));

create table Client (client_no varchar(10), client_name char(10), property_no varchar(10), foreign 
key(property_no) references Property(property_no),primary key(client_no,client_name,property_no));

create table Owner (owner_no varchar(10), owner_name char(10), property_no varchar(10), foreign 
key(property_no) references Property(property_no), primary key(owner_no,property_no));

insert into Property values('pg4', '6 Lawrence St.', '2000-01-07','2001-8-31', 50);
insert into Property values('pg16', '5 Novar Dr.', '2001-09-01','2002-9-1', 70);
insert into Property values('pg4', '6 Lawrence St.', '1999-09-02','2000-6-10', 50);
insert into Property values('pg36', '2 Manor Rd', '2000-10-10','2001-12-1', 60);
insert into Property values('pg16', '5 Novar Dr.', '2002-11-1','2003-8-10', 70);

insert into owner values('co40', 'tina', 'pg4');
insert into owner values('co93', 'tony', 'pg16');
insert into owner values('co93', 'tony', 'pg36');

insert into Client values('cr56','aline', 'pg4');
insert into Client values('cr56','aline', 'pg36');
insert into Client values('cr56','aline', 'pg16');
insert into Client values('cr76','john', 'pg4');
insert into Client values('cr76','john', 'pg16');
```

I am trying to print output as below.

[image]

I tried the query below which gives me weird output:

```
Select  c.client_No
     , p.property_No
     ,  c.client_Name
     , p.p_address
     , p.rent_start
     , p.rent_finish
     , DATEDIFF(p.rent_finish, p.rent_start) as Total_Days
     , p.Rent_Per_Day
     , DATEDIFF(p.rent_finish, p.rent_start)*p.Rent_Per_Day as Total_Rent
     , o.owner_No
     , o.owner_name 
 from Property p 
 right 
  join  Client c 
    on p.property_no = c.property_no 
  left 
  join Owner o 
    on p.property_no = o.property_no
 group 
    by property_no
     , rent_start
 order 
    by client_no desc
     , property_no desc;
```

Output is :

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your table was not properly normalize. On tables "Client" and "Property" as your property_no also depends on rent start and finish.

Answer (score 1):

You main problem is not the query, but the tables:

- The tables are invalid and the create statements should be rejected by the DBMS.
- The table you call Property is actually a renting table, because its primary key is not the property number, but the property number plus the renting time. You should consider renaming the table, so people reading the queries know what they are dealing with.
- The table Client tries to reference the property table, but does this by property number only. The property number is not unique in the property table. This reference (foreign key) should hence not be allowed.
- The client table's primary key doesn't seem to make sense. Why are both client number and client name in the key? That means that both can have duplicates (e.g. the same number used for several clients as long as these have different names). And why is the property number in the key? Does each property have their own client numbers? A client can even have a property multiple times thus as long as they always use a different name.
- Same for the table Owner. You are referencing the property table by only part of its key which should be forbidden. Then, this doesn't seem to be the owner table, but rather an ownership table, because you don't only store the owner (number and name), but also a property. And with the primary key being owner number plus property number, this allows multiple owners to share the same property and it allows owners to use a different owner name with each of their properties. This looks completely wrong.

As to the query:

- Please don't ever mix right and left joins. This makes queries close to unreadable. Use left outer joins only (and only if you really want to outer join of course).
- The joins are leading to cartesian products, because while you think you are dealing with a property table, you are really dealing with a rent table, as described above.
- The query is invalid, because you group by property number and rent start only, but access columns unrelated to the group. The property/rent table for instance is allowed to contain many rows for such a combination, all with a different rent end (which is another error in the create table statement of course). You can also have multiple clients for a rent. Etc. Dont' ever use `GROUP BY` in order to fix something you don't understand in your query. Use it only when aggregating (i.e. having aggregate functions, such as `MIN`, `MAX` annd `COUNT`).

All in all: there is a lot to fix. Start with the tables. Read up normalization. A property should be identified by the property number, an owner by their owner number, the clients by their client numbers. ("Identified by" means primary key.) Then you'll want a separate table for the rentings.

Comment: What would be table structures and constraints here then. Can you elaborate one with example so that I can fix it with reference to that. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: As mentioned: A property should be identified by its property number only. It has an address and probably an owner. It doesn't have a date. Do you want to try this and I tell you whether you got it right?